# typeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable - PCA in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

I'm trying to perform Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on a rescaled dataset using Python and NumPy, but I'm encountering an error. Here's my code:

```
# We delete the first column "Instruments"

df_ESG_stock_Selection = df_ESG_stock_Selection.iloc[ : ,[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
df_ESG_stock_Selection

# Data transformation

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(df_ESG_stock_Selection)
rescaledDataset = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df_ESG_stock_Selection), columns = df_ESG_stock_Selection.columns,
                             index = df_ESG_stock_Selection.index)

## PCA Development

pca = PCA()
PCA_Result = pca.fit_transform(rescaledDataset)

componente1 = PrincipalComponent[:,0]
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 pca = PCA()
      2 PCA_Result = pca.fit_transform(rescaledDataset)
      3 
      4 componente1 = PrincipalComponent[:,0]

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it?

Description: I'm trying to apply PCA to a rescaled dataset using Python and NumPy. However, when I run the code above, I encounter a "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is callable" error. I'm not sure what's causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Is this all of your code? `PCA` references a numpy array. If you think its supposed to be something else, then likely the variable PCA has been mistakenly assigned something different earlier in your code. This could happen in a jupyter notebook for example, just by playing around with code and then rerunning one of the cells.

Comment: It helps to write a fully running but minimal example of the problem. We don't know where PCA comes from in your code. Is it from sklearn or some other place?

Answer (score 1):

Watch out, you misread the error, it's NOT a callable. The issue appears to be that the name `PCA` is a `numpy.ndarray`. Did you write something like `PCA = somendarray` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Sounds right.  Op might want to try doing the `PCA` import again to replace any other use of that name

Comment: @SamMason he shouldnt assign that name at all, its really bad practice, if he insists on using that name for his variable, he should at least rename the import using `as` for example

Comment: yup, agree that "shadowing" variable names like this is generally a bad idea (e.g. it can lead to the confusion that prompted this question).  I was mostly suggesting this to help them diagnose what was going on rather than as a long-term fix.  Should maybe have been more explicit about that...

Comment: Ok, yeah understandable. I just wanted to be very explicit about that because it could shoot him or someone else in the foot in the future, sorry if it sounded a little harsh